# "Must read "papers on analytic number theory

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, soft-question, big-list, analytic-number-theory

> Question: What would be some must-read
>   papers for an aspiring analytic number
>   theorist? In other words, what are the papers that any analytic number theorist would have read? (Background: Someone who has seen some classical analytic number theory, at the level of Davenport and modular forms books by Iwaniec)

There are some classical papers that comes to mind. For example,

- Duke-Friedlander-Iwaniec's work on subconvexity bounds
- Iwaniec's 1987 paper on bounding Fourier coefficients of half-integral weight modular forms
- Duke's work on Linnik's problems

Basically I would like to collect papers that any graduate student in analytic number theory should have read/should be aware of. In particular I am interested in something more modern (although very classical papers such as Riemann's memoir is still welcome, for the sake of completeness) Thank you.

Edit: In light of Professor Garrett's comment, I am trying to restrict the scope a little bit. (Hopefully it's now more reasonable) Analytic number theory is a pretty diverse area, but hopefully there is a reasonable list of papers that every analytic number theorist would have read/know about.

Comment: There are probably at least 100, if not a large factor more... if only because "analytic number theory" has many different senses, and many different corresponding notions of "background". Surely a list of 1000 papers would not be a desired answer... Clarification is needed, or else some sort of acknowledgement of "oops, so there's no royal road..."?

Comment: Dear Professor @paul garrett, let me start by an "oops". At the same time, since everyone has only so much time in grad school, there is hopefully still a list of papers that one should go through DURING GRAD SCHOOL for someone interested in analytic number theory. Or is this still hopelessly broad? In that case, I would be grateful if you have any suggestion to make the scope of the question more reasonable. Thank you again.

Comment: The proof of the Brauer–Siegel theorem (e.g. as presented in Lang's book), though probably that's something that you'll do regardless / have already done. I know some people who like Soundararajan and Ono's paper titled "Ramanujan's ternary quadratic form."

Comment: Are you interested in additive number theory? Multiplicative number theory? Nonabelian harmonic analysis?

Comment: @Jonah Sinick, thanks for your reply. I am more interested in the latter two.

Comment: I feel like Iwaniec and Kowalski's "Analytic Number Theory" is a great guide to the further literature. I would suggest to an aspiring analytic number theorist that he or she first read Davenport, then start reading parts of IK, then follow up on whichever parts of IK seem most interesting. "Opera de Cribro" by Friedlander and Iwaniec is another great book that discusses much of the very recent literature. Also, Soundararajan has some excellent survey papers (such as "The Distribution of the Primes") with more references. There's *much* more out there, I am interested in other responses too.

Comment: @Frank Thorne, thanks for your reply. I know that there are many cool stuff out there (say in IK), yet I want to pick out the most important papers that basically every analytic number theorist should know. Based on this criterion, perhaps I would like to ask whether most analytic number theorists would be familiar with sieve theory as in FI, or everything in IK?

Comment: I'd venture to bet that now with your restriction, taken in a strict sense, you are asking for the empty-set. I doubt there is even a single paper everybody (or even almost everybody) that qualifies as analytic number theorist has read. On a more serious note: what *books* have *you* already read? 

Comment: This question is too broad and your background is unclear. I am not an analytic number theorist, but I'll throw in my two cents. Weil's "explicit formula" paper and the paper where he proves the converse to Hecke's lemma. Selberg's collected works.

Comment: I think that most analytic number theorists have at least a passing familiarity with the entire contents of IK, and know a little bit about sieve methods, but most of the successful young analytic number theorists I know started doing research before reading a lot of the literature. However, I think Iwaniec encourages his students to read very heavily in grad school, and several of them are *extremely* successful; you would certainly benefit by mastering any of his books.

Comment: @quid, I have read Davenport, and two books by Iwaniec on automorphic forms. (Also part of Diamond and Shurman's modular form for that matter, though that's not so analytic)

Comment: I think that this question is too broad to answer, as ANT has nowadays several different flavours, spreading from spectral theory of automorphic representations and equidistribution to classical sieving problems to additive number theory to arithmetic combinatorics and exponential sums to arithmetic geometry and Hardy-Littlewood method, just to name a few. 

There is no one explicit correct answer here, and the choice of must-read articles would change from one expert to another (even in the same field).

A good place to start seeing several of those flavours is in Sarnak's surveys.

Comment: @Asaf, thanks for your comment. I definitely did not expect a single correct answer. (Intended to make this some kind of big-list question) I saw similar questions in topology (Kan seminar for example), or numerical analysis (a question asked on MO), and I thought that there's perhaps a similar list in analytic number theory which would really help me in building up a general foundation in Analytic NT, as I was afraid that dabbling in a specific problem I have in hand would make me too specialized early on in my career. But perhaps the question is too broad to be answerable.

Comment: @Felipe Voloch, thanks for your comment. Perhaps Selberg's collected works (+Iwaniec-Kowalski perhaps) would be the closest to what I look for now.